# Kibana: vega-lite visualizations if data result is empty

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elk, vega-lite, vega

I'm trying to create a vega-lite visualization with a query. But if the result of the query is return empty, I get the "cannot read property 'xx' undefined" message. Some part of my visualization code is below:

```
{
  $schema: https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v2.6.0.json
  data: {
    name: our_data
    url: {
      index: index-7.0.1-index*
      body: {
        query: {
          bool: {
            filter: [
              {
                match_all: {}
              }
              {
                match_all: {}
              }
            ]
            should: []
            must_not: []
          }
        }
        aggs: {
          xx: {
            top_hits: {
              docvalue_fields: [
                {
                  field: someField
                  format: use_field_mapping
                }
                
              ]
              _source: ["someField"]
              size: 1
              sort: [
                {
                  @timestamp: {order: "desc"}
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    format: {property: "aggregations.xx.hits.hits"}
  }
```

Is there any way not to get "cannot read property 'xx' undefined" message? I just want if there is no data result, vega-lite visualization looks blank.

Thank you.

Comment: This is not a valid Vega-Lite data specification. Can you clarify what tools you are using?

Comment: @jakevdp which part is not valid? If data result is not empty, it works.

Comment: The Vega-Lite schema does not support `index` and `body` mappings in its `data` attribute (see the [Vega-Lite Data docs](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/data.html)); if you put the above specification into the [vega editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/) it will result in an error. If that specification is producing something, you are not using Vega-Lite alone. Can you clarify what tools you are using?

Comment: I use kibana and elasticsearch 7.0.1. I try to create this vega-lite visualization in kibana. @jakevdp